# Auto Refresh Div content without refreshing the page (no external script used)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to update the content of a div. I am creating a chat box and I don't want to refresh the whole page on entering the message. I just want the div to be refreshed. The div has the embedded code and no external script is used.
my code :

```
<div class="direct-chat-messages" id='chatlogs'>
             <?php  
                    include "connect.php";

                    $q121=mysql_query("Select DISTINCT full_date as full_date, date from chats where (employee_id='$employee_id' and chat_id='$chat_id') or (employee_id='$chat_id' and chat_id='$employee_id')") or die(mysql_error());
                    if(mysql_num_rows($q121) > 0)
                    {
                    while($r211=mysql_fetch_array($q121)){
                        $full_date1=$r211['full_date'];
                        $date1=$r211['date'];
                    ?>

                    <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                                <abbr class="timestamp"><?php echo $r211['full_date']; ?></abbr>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $q122=mysql_query("Select * from chats where date='$date1' and (chat_id='$employee_id' or employee_id='$employee_id') and (chat_id='$chat_id' or employee_id='$chat_id') ORDER BY time ASC") or die(mysql_error());
                    if(mysql_num_rows($q122) > 0)
                    {
                        while($r22=mysql_fetch_array($q122)){
                            $employee_id1=$r22['employee_id'];
                            $chat_id1=$r22['chat_id'];
                            if(($employee_id1 === $employee_id) || ($chat_id1 === $employee_id))
                            {
                    ?>
    <div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left"><?php echo $first; ?></span>
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp"><?php echo $r22['time']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        <?php echo $r22['msg'];?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <?php
                            }
                            else 
                                if(($employee_id1 === $chat_id) || ($chat_id1 === $chat_id)){
    ?>
    <div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-namei pull-left"><?php echo $we1['fname'];?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        <?php echo $r22['msg'];?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right"><?php echo $r22['time']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php                       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    ?>
                  </div>
```

Comment: where is the ajax code and in which div you want the content to load ?

Comment: It's not possible to refresh div without reload page via PHP. You must use PHP with combination of AJAX

Comment: I want to reload the content of div with id "chatlogs".

Comment: $(document).ready(function(e){
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('insert1.php');}, 2000); 
 });
This is the code that I found, but again it loads an external script in the div. I am not using any external script

Answer (score 0):

Instead of injecting content to div you can use the concept of virtual DOM that is used by [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/). For updating page without reloading you can use [Flux Architecture](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html), so if there is any change in the database it will trigger the all views to change its state. Updating page without reloading can't be achieved without javascript.